# How do I hide a constructor?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to build a type `LazyList` but hide the definition of `LazyList.t`. I've got the following files:

LazyList.ml

```
type 'a t =
    | Cell of ('a * 'a t) option Lazy.t
;;

let rec from_list l = ...;;
let rec from_string s = ...;;
let rec from_in_channel c = ...;;

let rec to_list l = ...;;
```

LazyList.mli

```
type 'a t;;

val from_list : 'a list -> 'a t;
val from_string : string -> char t;
val from_in_channel : in_channel -> char t;

val to_list : 'a t -> 'a list;
```

When I run `ocamlc LazyList.mli` I get the following error:

```
File "LazyList.mli", line 1, characters 9-10:
Error: Syntax error
```

What gives? Do I need to expose the constructor if I'm going to be writing all of the methods I need in LazyList.ml?

Comment: The single constructor doesn't look useful, and does impose some overhead: consider removing it entirely.

Comment: How would I do that? I thought that the type needed a constructor to be recursive.

Comment: The `-rectypes` option allows such type definitions. Another possibility is defining the type differently, something like `type 'a t = Nil | Cons of ('a * 'a t) Lazy.t` (but you'd have to rewrite your code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only a syntax error. Semicolons cannot appear in mli file. Also you really do not need to use this ugly double semicolons in ml file, although it is not an error.

Comment: Wow. Now I feel really dumb. Thanks for the help!